# Unable to find audio : Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I want to use the audio that I have uploaded on firebase but getDownloadUrl is not returning the correct value due to which it cannot find the audio on firebase. Also, the user is authenticated using phone Number.

code:

```
 storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

StorageReference audioRef = storageReference.child(userPhoneNumber).child("audios").child("audio_" + photoNum );

Toast.makeText(APIActivity.this, "here " + audioRef.getDownloadUrl().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

audioRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Uri audioUri) {
        try{
            Toast.makeText(APIActivity.this, "onSuccess method", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), audioUri);
            mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    mp.start();
                }
            });
        }catch(IOException e){
            Toast.makeText(APIActivity.this, "Cannot play audio", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(APIActivity.this, "Cannot find audio", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

I'm receiving the toast : Cannot find audio. 
Also, its throwing StorageException and says object does not exist.

Image of audios on Firebase console:
[image: Image of audios on Firebase console]

Comment: Check out `e.toString()` to see what the cause of the failure is.

Comment: Toast is not a terribly effective debugging tool.  Try logging to get better error information.  `Log.e(TAG, "error", e)`

Comment: @DougStevenson I did that,  its throwing StorageException and says object does not exist.

Comment: Then you should check the path that you're trying to access, and make sure the file exists in storage with exactly that path.